# Convert do "código de data" do Excel

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, data

boa tarde!

Preciso importar uma planilha excel para o SQL e nessa planilha tenho muitos campos de data.

No excel eu visualizo a data dessa forma "30/01/2020", porém quando eu imputo essa informação no banco, vem esse código "43860".

Alguém sabe a lógica desse código, pra que eu posso fazer uma logística reversa? (transformar no SQL o código 43860 em 30/01/2020).

Obrigada!

---

Resolvido

Obrigada a todos!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Retificando: 
Por algum motivo a conta deve ser DAY -2**

Seguem exemplos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece que ao longo desse tempo alguma data não consta no calendário (as vezes pode ser por conta de ano bissexto).

No exemplo acima, a data bateu somente quando fiz dateadd (data_x - 2, '1900/01/01')
Mas se eu fizer essa mesma lógica com a própria data '1900/01/01' o resultado seria '1899-12-31 00:00:00.000'

Comment: É só modificar o formato da célula de geral para `Data Hora` e escolher o formato de exibição de sua preferência. O Excel armazena datas no formato de dia juliano, isto é, a quantidade de dias decorridos a partir de uma data específica.

Comment: Esse número é a quantidade de dias contados a partir de 01/01/1900: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time#_Toc495931389 - se não me engano, basta formatar a coluna, mudando o tipo para "Data", que ele mostra corretamente

Comment: Sim, eu consigo corrigir isso na mão, porém será uma importação recorrente e gostaria de automatizar sem ter que colocar a mão, entendem?
Por isso gostaria de saber como corrigir diretamente no SQL
Mas obrigada pela ajuda pessoal :)

hkotsubo, obrigada! vou validar pra ver se dá certo e volto aqui pra falar.

Comment: Até porque também tenho muitos campos de data, são mais de 10 colunas no meio de 52 com outras informações. Quero reduzir ao máximo intervenções manuais

Comment: É só selecionar todas as colunas que contém datas (com CTRL) e formatá-las de uma só vez.

Comment: Pessoal, consegui com a função dateadd

Comment: Obrigada a todos que ajudaram :)

Comment: A Microsoft foi alertada a muitos anos atrás deste problema mas eles não corrigiram justificando que era a maneira com que o Lotus-123 fazia e eles queriam manter a compatibilidade, mesmo que errado.

Comment: @Bruna Favor [edit] a pergunta e retirar a resposta. E [responder a própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/75104)

Comment: Feito. Obrigada! :)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO 2

Achei um BUG no excel em relação à data

o Excel conta o dia 29/02/1900 como data, porém essa data não existe de acordo com o calendário oficial.

Já o SQL não conta como data, por isso existe essa diferença de números (de -1 pra -2)

Ou seja, está validado.

A fórmula que podemos usar neste caso é:

> declare @data_excel int 
>          set @data_excel = 43860
>
> SELECT DATEADD(day, @data_excel-2, '1900/01/01') AS DateAdd;